# Variável retornando Undefined

Tags: angular

Preciso recuperar o valor de um **p** que fica dentro de um de meus components, esse **p** recebe o valor da minha API quando a página é carregada.

Para fazer isso, eu fiz um **[(ngModel)]="usuarioDestino"** e criei uma variável **usuarioDestino** que deveria receber esse valor, porém no meu console.log ela é retornada como **undefined**.

**Paragrafo:**

```
<p class="card-text" [(ngModel)]="usuarioDestino" name="usuarioDestino" ngDefaultControl>ID:{{usuario.id}}</p>

usuarioDestino: string;
```

O valor desse P é carregado no onInit, portanto assim que a pagina carrega ele já está lá.

Podem me ajudar?

**Código completo:**

```
import { Component,  OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { UsuariosService } from '../../services/usuarios.service'
import { ModalComponent } from '../modal/modal.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-lista-usuarios',
  templateUrl: './lista-usuarios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lista-usuarios.component.css']
})
export class ListaUsuariosComponent implements OnInit {

  usuarios: Array<any> = new Array();
  usuarioDestino: string;


  constructor(private usuariosService: UsuariosService, private dialog: MatDialog ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsuarios();
    console.log(this.usuarioDestino);
  }


  getUsuarios(){
    this.usuariosService.userList().subscribe((resposta) => {
      this.usuarios = resposta;
      console.log(this.usuarios);
    });
  }


  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, {
      width: '800px',
    });
   
    const destino = this.usuarioDestino;
    console.log('Destino:', destino);
    
    

    dialogRef.componentInstance.usuarioDestino = this.usuarioDestino;

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
  }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="w-100 containerFlex" *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios">
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="{{usuario.img}}" class="card-img" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Nome de usuário: {{usuario.name}}  </h5>
              <p class="card-text" [(ngModel)]="usuarioDestino" name="usuarioDestino" ngDefaultControl>ID:{{usuario.id}}</p>
              <p class="card-text">{{usuario.username}}</p>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" (click)="openDialog()">Pagar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Acredito que o console.log que você chama não está no mesmo contexto de atuação da variável

Comment: Gustavo, pode me explicar melhor? Inseri o código completo na publicação para ficar mais fácil de identificar.

Comment: Pelo que vi no código, você não definiu valor para a variavel em this.usuarioDestino. O seu getUsuarios está defininfo valor para this.usuarios aprnas

Comment: Olha Bruno desculpe-me mais uma vez de insistir nesse ponto, mas, cara volta umas 1 ou 2 casinha pra trás aí, aprende primeiro o básico de HTML e Javascript puro, depois volta a aprender Angular, pq cara me parece que vc não tem a base. Elementos HTML **p** não possuem atributo `name`, qual o sentido de se utilizar **`ngModel`** em uma tag p, ele é utilizado em elementos de entrada como `input` e `select`, para isso que ele serve, para fazer a utilização bidirecional dos dados, do template para o TS, como fará isso em uma tag p?? Desse jeito só irá ficar batendo cabeça desnecessariamente!

Comment: LeAndrade, eu coloquei o ngModel porque quando executei o código, o console me retornou um erro pedindo um atributo name. Um input para mim não serviria nesse caso, esse campo é só para visualização, porém quando eu chamo o meu dialog eu tenho que enviar o valor que esse P exibe para eu poder preencher um objeto. Esse objeto eu pego diversos campos e ai eu faço um post em minha API.

Comment: LeAndrade, você tem uma sugestão de como posso resolver isso? Esse P recebe um valor da minha API que é o user.id. Eu tenho que exibir esse valor da API na minha aplicação, e também preciso enviar esse valor para o meu dialog, que tag eu deveria usar?

Comment: Fiz uma alteração, ao invés de usar o ngModel usei o ElementRef, porém ele pega apenas o primeiro usuário da minha lista. Preciso pegar o usuário do model que eu cliquei.

Comment: No código postado em nenhum momento a variável **usuarioDestino** recebe um valor, como espera que o valor dela não seja `undefined`?

Answer (score -2):

Cara, o `ngModel` não pode ser usado assim, ele é uma diretiva de inputs, no `<p>` ele acaba não fazendo nada (isso se não estiver gerando erros). A diretiva `ngDefaultControl` que você está usando serve para componentes que você criar no seu projeto e não para elementos do DOM.

Para resolver seu problema, você pode passar o id do usuário como parâmetro como a seguir:

```
<div class="w-100 containerFlex" *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios">
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="{{usuario.img}}" class="card-img" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Nome de usuário: {{usuario.name}}  </h5>
              <p class="card-text">ID:{{usuario.id}}</p>
              <p class="card-text">{{usuario.username}}</p>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" (click)="openDialog(usuario.id)">Pagar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

ou seja alterando o `(click)="openDialog()"` do `<button>` por `(click)="openDialog(usuario.id)"` e coloca um parâmetro para receber esse id na implementação do seu método!

```
  openDialog(id: string) { 
  ...
  }
```